# How to automate native "Search" button in Appium Java

Tags: selenium, mobile, native, appium, tap

```
driver.findElementById("SearchField").sendKeys("bacon");
```

After sending keys the Native Keyboard opens automatically on IOS.

How can i automate Tap on **native keyboard "Search"**?

Appium + Java + Selenium + Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java-client 3.1.0, you can use this:

```
    ((AndroidDriver) driver).sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are automating a native mobile application. then you can easily click on the search button.

driver.findElement(By.Xpath("xpath of search icon")).click();

If you are automating web application then you need to change your context to native like below.

**STEPS**

- Get the current context handles
- Save the current context Context to Native
- Change the Context to Native
- Click on the search button
- change the context to default

**CODE**

```
driver.getContextHandles();
String currentContext = driver.getContext();
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("xpath of search icon")).click();
driver.context(currentContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would be helpful for you since it's been half a year but I did have a similar problem. If I was going to search with "Bruno Mars" in the search field, I would just have appium type in "Bruno Mars\n" and the newline would automatically trigger the search button. However, recently my devices weren't responding to the new line anymore. I winded up downgrading the google keyboard to 4.1.x and I was able to use new line method again. The problem was that the devices had auto updated to to version 5.x. So downgrading the keyboard solved the issue for me.